# OS X how to designate startup viewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am developing a simple browser project on mac, i didn't use the default viewcontroller.

Instead, I write a viewcontroller class BrowserViewController. 
and write follow in appdelegate

```
@interface AppDelegate()
@property (nonatomic, strong) BrowserViewController *browserController;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
  // Insert code here to initialize your application
    self.browserController = [[BrowserViewController alloc] init];

    [self.window makeKeyWindow];
    [self.window setContentView:self.browserController.view];
}

@end
```

But when the app start up it lead to the default viewcontroller not the BrowserViewController. I really don't know the reason.

Thanks for the help, i have solve this problem. My solution is like this:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
//set the frame of the window fit to the device's frame
//
self.window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:[[NSScreen     mainScreen] frame] styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask     backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO ];

//
//
self.browserController = [[BrowserViewController alloc] init];


//set contentView
//
self.window.contentViewController = self.browserController;

//this is setting global backgroundColor of the window
//
self.window.backgroundColor = [NSColor whiteColor];

//this means the window is the window that will receive user interaction.
//
[self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
//[self.window makeKeyWindow];//NOTE: This is not working.
}
```

Comment: You should tag language, it makes your question easier to find, and it also changes the syntax highlighting of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select `Is Initial Controller` in the storyboard.

[image: storyboard]

Comment: thanks for the reply, it really let the app first not to lead to the default viewcontroller. but my BrowserViewcontroller didn't show. and then i replaced the [self.window makeKeyWindow]; to   [self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self]; , the BrowserViewController showed. I read the doc, - (void)makeKeyAndOrderFront:(id)sender
Description 
Moves the window to the front of the screen list, within its level, and makes it the key window; that is, it shows the window.   but  - (void)makeKeyWindow    only makes the window the key window.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just know that I should click the check to mark the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for (inside your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method):

```
self.browserController = [[BrowserViewController alloc] init];
[self.window setRootViewController: self.browserController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply~~My app is for os x and i can't find the setRootViewController method, i think it's just for IOS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it programmatically:

**Note**

This is for iOS, but the logic are identical. Hope this will be useful for some reason.. :)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //set the frame of the window fit to the device's frame
    //
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    //what you have above is correct
    //
    self.browserController = [[BrowserViewController alloc] init];

    //you can also directly set it like
    //
    BrowserViewController *mainView = [[BrowserViewController alloc] init];

    //this is the most important, you need to set the window's rootViewController
    //
    self.window.rootViewController = mainView;

    //this is setting global backgroundColor of the window
    //
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    //this means the window is the window that will receive user interaction.
    //
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Hope this is helpful and informative.. Cheers! :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your solution is for IOS, and my app is for os x. setRootViewController method does not fit for OS X. but i have solve the problem just like your steps and i find the key problem is to replace the makeKeyWindow method with makeKeyAndOrderFront: method. Thanks~~~

Comment: @melody5417, Sorry about that, i did note highlighted that one. hmm. but ios and os x programming logic are like identical.. and you are welcome. :)